# How can I change printer using the chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, printers

How can I change printer using the chrome extension?

[image]

EDIT:
I want to use the extension to change the printer depending on the report I want. For example: A4 printer, A5 printer, thermal printer (epson)

Comment: I want to use the extension to change the printer depending on the report I want.
For example: A4 printer, A5 printer, thermal printer (epson)

Comment: Extensions can't do that but extensions can save to PDF directly by using `chrome.debugger` API (look for examples yourself) and sending [Page.printToPDF](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF) command.